# The Method size() is not undefined for the type Android Element

Tags: java, android, appium

Getting error like The Method size() is not undefined for the type Android Element in below line of code

```
System.out.println(driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().clickable(true)").size());
```

Answer (score 0):

`findElementByAndroidUIAutomator` method returns a single element and hence `size()` method does not apply on it.
If you want to get the `size()`, you need to fetch the list of the element which you can fetch by using `findElementsByAndroidUIAutomator` method.

Your line of code should be:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElementsByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().clickable(true)").size());
```